# Return css edits when Google Books API have no image

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to overwrite css to show up author and title of the book when there is no image for this book in Google Books API.

Right now user see custom image linked here, but he has no idea what it is without name + author info.

```
const extractThumbnail = ({ imageLinks }) => {
const DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL = "https://www.bindly.pl/static/images/logo.svg";
if (!imageLinks || !imageLinks.thumbnail) {
    return DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL;
}
return imageLinks.thumbnail.replace("http://", "https://");};
```

So instead of `return DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL;` i would like to remove image and add css:

```
document.querySelector("div.book-info ").style.display = "inline-flex;";
document.querySelector("h3.book-title").style.fontsize = "32px";
```

But those seems to doesnt work...

Any idea? Heres whole code

```
let bookContainer = document.querySelector(".search");
let searchBooks = document.getElementById("search-box");
const getBooks = async(book) => {
    const response = await fetch(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${book}&langRestrict=pl&printType=books`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
};

const extractThumbnail = ({ imageLinks }) => {
    const DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL = "https://www.bindly.pl/static/images/logo.svg";
    if (!imageLinks || !imageLinks.thumbnail) {
        return DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL;
    }
    return imageLinks.thumbnail.replace("http://", "https://");
};




const drawChartBook = async(subject, startIndex = 0) => {
    let cbookContainer = document.querySelector(`.${subject}`);
    cbookContainer.innerHTML = `<div class='prompt'><div class="loader"></div></div>`;
    const cdata = await getBooks(
        `subject:${subject}&startIndex=${startIndex}&maxResults=3`
    );
    if (cdata.error) {
        cbookContainer.innerHTML = `<div class='prompt'></div>`;
    } else if (cdata.totalItems == 0) {
        cbookContainer.innerHTML = `<div class='prompt'></div>`;
    } else if (cdata.totalItems == undefined) {
        cbookContainer.innerHTML = `<div class='prompt'>ツ Ups, chyba masz problem z internetem!</div>`;
    } else if (!cdata.items || cdata.items.length == 0) {
        cbookContainer.innerHTML = `<div class='prompt'>ツ Niestety, nie ma więcej wyników!</div>`;
    } else {
        cbookContainer.innerHTML = cdata.items;
        cbookContainer.innerHTML = cdata.items
            .map(
                ({ volumeInfo }) =>
                `<div class='book' style='background: linear-gradient(` +
                getRandomColor() +
                `, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));'><a href='https://www.bindly.pl/${volumeInfo.authors}/${volumeInfo.title}' target='_blank'><img class='thumbnail' src='` +
                extractThumbnail(volumeInfo) +
                `' alt='cover'></a><div class='book-info'><h3 class='book-title'><a href='https://www.bindly.pl/${volumeInfo.authors}/${volumeInfo.title}' target='_blank'>${volumeInfo.title}</a></h3><div class='book-authors' onclick='updateFilter(this,"author");'>${volumeInfo.authors}</div></div></div>`
            )
            .join("");
        document.querySelector(".search-box").style.background = "#f00;";

    }
};
```

Comment: May be https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates#templates-syntax

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that at the point you are doing:

```
document.querySelector("div.book-info ").style.display = "inline-flex;";
document.querySelector("h3.book-title").style.fontsize = "32px";
```

[incidentally there are syntax errors here, the ; before the " in the first line and fontsize should be fontSize - but they are not the reason for your problem assuming you , are calling this code in the extractThumbnail function.]

the elements you are looking for are not yet in the DOM - they are not actually even yet in the string you are building up to eventually put into the document.

One thing you could do is create strings in the extractThumbnail function that later you then add in to the HTML you are building up. So, you could have a string which is the whole thumbnail img element - and if there isn't a thumbnail make that string null. Another string e.g. ' style="display: inline-flex;"' and another for the font-size. Then add them into the HTML string as you build it up having called the extractThumbnail function in advance.

I don't know whether extractThumbnail is used elsewhere. If it is, write your own version for this particular instance with a different name so nothing else gets affected.